# Checking an array of input boxes are not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, submit

Preferably wanting to do this in jQuery, simple validation to check if the input boxes are empty. However, these are a dynamic array of input boxes. The code should help make more sense:

```
<input type="text" id="qtn" name="question" />
<input type="text" name="answer[]" />
<button type="button" id="btn"> Save </button>
```

I understand the usual idea for the question input would involve something like this:

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    var question = $.trim($('#qtn').val());

    // Check if empty of not
    if (question === '') {
        alert('Text-field is empty.');
        return false;
    } else {
        $('#form').submit();
    }
});
```

How would this work for the `answer[]` input type as there will be a dynamic number of answers and want to make sure that however many the user has selected, that all these boxes are filled.

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean, it should validate all input boxes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `filter()` method to find any empty text boxes in the `form`. Also note that you should do this check on submission of the `form` itself, not the click of a button, as someone could submit the form by pressing the return key while the focus is on a textbox. Try this:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    var $emptyFields = $(this).find(':text').filter(function() {
        return this.value.trim() == '';
    });

    if (!$emptyFields.length) {
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the form submission
        alert('Please fill out all fields');
    } else {
        $form.submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Good answer, love the use of filter. I would also suggest adding a "required" class to the inputs that you want to validate, so you exclude non-required fields you might have later.  You could also add an "error" class to the emptyfields to highlight the errors for the user.

Comment: This seems to cause my form to actually submit when anywhere within the form area is clicked? Even when clicking inside a input text box?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
   var checkValidate = false;
   $('input[type=text]').each(function() {
          if(!$.trim($(this).val())){
            alert('Some fields are empty');
            checkValidate = true;
            return false;
          }
   });
   if(!checkValidate) {
      $('#form').submit();
   }
});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/3119/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    var getTargetText = $(":text").filter(function() { return this.value==""; });
    if($(getTargetText[0]).val()=="") {
        alert("Please Enter this Field");
        $(getTargetText[0]).focus();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Yup, as **Rory McCrossan**'s Answer, filter would be the option. i just modified to target which actual text box is null.